# What is an elegant way to convert the result of [x for x in y] from list to a regular variable?

Tags: python

What is an elegant way to convert the result of `[x for x in y]` from list to a regular variable?

```
result= [x for x in range(10) if x==7]
```

The result of the above will be `[7]`.
I am now using `result=result[0]` but ...it does not look right :-)

thanks

Comment: `result= [x for x in range(10) if x==7][0]`

Comment: :-)) I love you guys. I am still learning python. amazing language

Comment: `[]` generates a list. Be careful, can you assert that only one element will pass the filter? Only then is makes sense to drop it. Otherwise you need some logic to choose the element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a list comprehension on the right hand side. It evaluates to a list.

You want to pick up the first element (which is perhaps the only element for the kind of problems you are trying to solve) from it, so index the 0-th element in the list returned by the list comprehension, just like you would do it for a regular list.

```
result = [x for x in range(10) if x == 7][0]
```

You can also use a generator expression instead of a list expression and then call the [next()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next) function to retrieve the first item from the iterator returned by the generator expression.

```
result = next(x for x in range(10) if x == 7)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `next` that retrieves the next object from the iterator. The parameter that goes within `next` is a *[generator](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators)*. This allows saves you from fully constructing the list and then filtering for `7`. Instead it only iterates until it hits `7`, and wont evaluate until the next `next(..)` is called on the generator object.

```
>>> next(x for x in range(10) if x==7)
7
```

Comment: isn't range a generator in python 3? In that case it works properly even without next() (use xrange in python 2)

Comment: Correct, I should have used `xrange(..)` instead of `range(..)` since I was writing Python2 -- that would have saved creating a list of 10 items. On Python3, you'd still have to use `next(..)` because you need the first element that has value equal to 7.